# Anyone used kinect v2 for contour mapping?

Tags: contour, kinect-v2

kinectv2 library for contour mapping?

I can't find any libraries for kinectv2 to contour mapping. I want to get a depth information and draw the contours on sand from kinectv2 and want to heat mapping. Anyone have the code for these plz help me